# Service Worker generated by workbox-build can't work in Chrome 50

Tags: javascript, web, frontend, service-worker

I use `workbox-build` to build `/sw-workbox.js` and add it the my page, it works well in new version of Chrome, but I try to test it in old versions of Chrome like Chrome 50, the debugger shows the errror below:
[image]

It seems there is some syntax error in the `/sw-workbox.js` file, so is there any similar case? And how to configure `work-build` to build a service worker file which can work well in old versions of browser like Chrome 50?

Comment: Chrome **50** like from 6 years ago?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, but my page is still running in Chrome 50 browser core.

Comment: Why?  Chrome pushes users to upgrade their browser aggressively.  Almost nobody is using a version of Chrome that old.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The case is my page is running at electron APP based on Chrome 50 core, and it's hard to upgrade recently.